# Migrating from Lotus database to MySql and MSSqlServer

Tags: schema, lotus-domino, database-migration, lotus

I'm migrating an application and data from old lotus database / notes to 1) MySql and 2) MS Sql Server and .NET C#. I found an interop with the dominos.dll library, which has been flaky at best. Seeing this and being concerned about the port, they have asked me to support the old Lotus DB, and the new db's in tandem for 3 months (something I wasn't ready to do).

1. Is there a wizard or 3rd party tool to extract the schema and migrate into MySql or MSSql Server
2. Besides the domino.dll is there another option, to integrate programmatically
3. How can I safely support both in tandem for a short period of time -  is there a sync or replay mechanisim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to migrate Lotus Notes databases to SQL server based db's in the past.  I've used two different methods:

1st: Notes agent to create CSV files - then import into SQL database

2nd: Use Lotus Enterprise Integrator (LEI) to translate data and populate SQL database.

1st method can be a pain but very flexible, 2nd method is easier if you have LEI but not as flexible.  As you say, you could use the Notes driver and push data directly into SQL but you're effectively using the 1st method.

You may wish to extract the UNID and $REF fields from the source documents so that you can preserve the hierarchy of documents (parent/child).

If the underlying Notes Database contains objects (not text) in RTF fields then you will not capture this data using the above methods.

Have a look on youtube - there are some videos about migrating from Notes to Sharepoint - may give you some pointers.  Best of luck, Phil

Comment: Also, if you want to migrate data whilst the Notes database is still in use then the following has worked for me:

Comment: Phil thanks for the reply, I am hunting around to see if I can LEI. I', wondering how other organizations extract and sunset Notes. Also, Stack Overflow wont let me vote up, apparently don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: Most of the larger companies have > Notes apps - combination of client and web.  Alot of these apps are never used but it still maybe the case that the data has to be kept for x number of years (legal compliance).  Replacing Notes functionality using another application (Sharepoint for example) would be interesting - bet some people frown when the look at the @formula behind a button or computed field and see pages of the stuff!  Reminds me of the migration from Lotus 123 to Excel - same issue for complex apps.  My guess that the current migration offerings 'sort of' work (to a degree).

Comment: For reference purposes - easy to extract the data, dump to SQL and write a front end ASP app (or whatever to display the data) - guess you could even define the layout of the data when exporting it (like a template) and then have the ASP build the page as described by the 'template' ...

Comment: 1) Is there a **Tool, or import Utility** in SQL server/Access/MySql or even Excel to get the data out of lotus notes, with its schema. 2) Is there a way to lock the Lotus DB in that timeframe.

Comment: I'm not aware of a tool - please let me know if you find something!  I guess the issue is that to understand the data extracted (and therefore present to a user) you need to understand how the Notes app is designed/built (forms, views, etc).  There are numerous ways of extracting the data but not (as far as I'm aware - and pretty sure) the 'schema'.

Comment: If the migrated data is just for 'read only' purposes then you could develop a simple 'schema' type definition (manually configured for that specific app) - examine the Notes app and manually complete a 'schema' for that app - then export the data.  I guess you could have standard 'schemas' for Notes db's created from templates (discussion forum etc).  How many Notes apps you looking at exporting and is the exported data just for read only purposes?

Comment: Also, please bear in mind that the design of a Notes database can change over time and it may not be the case that the underlying data was 'managed' to fit the new design.  Eg someone may have created a field representing a date but stored it as TEXT - later the design may have been updated to store as a DATE type.  When exporting this field you may therefore encounter data which doesn't match your expected field type.  You may also find orphaned documents - relationship lost to parent document.

Comment: can you share a sample of your LEI script, I dont have Lotus, and am wondering how to implement this. Also, where does this script run, server client, inside lotus on the command shell?

Answer (score 3):

In short: There is no Schema for Lotus Notes Databases... Lotus Domino is a rapid development environment. Its databases contain documents, that can contain whatever data the designer of the app has designed them to contain. One database can contain various types of data and it is not even guaranteed, that every document of the same type (equals same `Form` in Domino) contains the same items, as definitions are not strict.

Documents can contain richtext and one ore more attachments, both not easy to handle when mogration to anpther database.

Functions can be written in Lotus Formula, LotusScript, Java, JavaScript and more.

Without a deep knowledge of the application or at least knowledge how to analyze one, it is nearly impossible to `migrate` it to another plattform. Keeping two plattforms at the same time and keep them in sync is a LOT of programming work.

Because of all the complexity there is no tool to buy, that can do this job for you...

There are a lot of possibilities to get domino data:
Interop.dll, CORBA / DIIOP, Webservices, and even a SQL driver for domino databaes. But without knowing the database and without knowledge how to do this, all these are worth nothing.

Sorry to say, but you will need professional help, or it will be a never ending story of unsatisfied users and lost data and functionality...

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. From your description it seems a little like a NoSql Document Database! Having said that. 1) If I had no choice, and could sunset the Lotus app - what path / steps would you recommend in getting data over to a Sql Server or such. 2) Is there a way to export all the data or import it once and do a cut over

Comment: As various as the ways for writing notes databases are, as various are the ways for exporting the data. You can have excel files, flat text files, html, you can directly export to an SQL database using Lsx connection Library for LotusScript or Java, etc, etc. But again: there is no "easy" way with just some clicks to do this. For an experienced Lots Notes Developer it might be a matter of hours or even minutes, to get your data exported, depending on the complexity of the app. I personally would use my (self written) tools to directly pump the data into the Sql db...

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to migrate data whilst the Notes database is still in use then the following has worked for me:  You need a complete/final state for the Notes document - once complete prevent edits (with msg 'this data has been migrated etc') - migrate data and flag document as migrated - migration agent then only searches for documents with a status of 'complete' but not 'migrated'.  used this method to migrate Northumbria eOASys db to standard NPD eOAsys whilst still in use.  Long winded approach but works.  Should really put some effort into developing an application to migrate Notes databases - quite an interesting project!